# Underling text when typing (suggestion?). I want to disable this

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, text

With the upgrade to xubuntu 18.04, when I type in certain softwares (like mono-develop, geany), the word I'm writing is underlined and when I press space it does something like the smartphone autocorrection.

I want to disable this. I haven't found any setting to disable this. I searched on Google but it seems I'm the only one with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu, but to the applications. A google on `mono-develop spell check` gave this link: https://answers.unity.com/questions/408956/monodevelop-autocorrect-annoyance.html .. there might be something similar for geany and other applications.

Comment: @SorenA, this isn't the issue, I tried your solution anyway but it didn't solve anything. This is not about a certain app, it's something system-wide

Answer (score 0):

Since I visit this question again and again I am leaving an answer for future me...

Hey! It's called 'candidate word'

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

[image: candidate word]